# C++ - framework for computing PCA (other than armadillo)

Tags: c++, pca, armadillo

I have a large dataset of around `200000` data points where each data point contains `132` features. So basically my dataset is `200000 x 132`.

I have done all the computations by using the [armadillo framework](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). However, I have tried to do PCA analysis but I received a memory error which I don't know that it's because of my RAM memory( 8 GB of Ram ) or its a limitation due to the framework itself.

I receive the following error : `requested size is too large`.

Can you recommend me another framework for PCA computation which doesn't have size/memory limtations?

Or if you have previously used armadillo for PCA computation and encountered this issue, can you tell me how you managed to solve it?

Comment: Would it be possible to divide your dataset to a smaller subsets, and then aggregate the results?

Comment: I don't know how to combine the results from different PCA steps. Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: well another framework won't help you, the only thing you can try with such an oddly shaped matrix is going to quad precision or higher if double failed to avoid numerical round off errors

Comment: Can you not find the 132 x 132 covariance matrix, then all or a top few eigenvectors, as described in [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis] ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable the use of [64 bit integers](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp) within Armadillo, which are used for storing the total number of elements, etc.

Specifically, edit the file 
**include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp**
and uncomment the line with: `// #define ARMA_64BIT_WORD`.
In version 3.4 this should be near line 59.

Alternatively, you can define ARMA_64BIT_WORD before including the Armadillo header in your program, eg:

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
...
```

Note that your C++ compiler must be able to handle 64 bit integers. Most compilers these days have it.

Comment: btw, if that doesn't work, it could be an issue with the underlying LAPACK function. In that case, you may wish to try the [svd_econ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svd_econ) function.

Comment: I receive the following error : `error: svd_econ(): failed to converge`

Comment: It usually means the problem is ill-posed or the solution is numerically ustable (ie. the SVD is not doable by LAPACK).