# Armadillo princomp out of memory

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, pca, armadillo

I'm trying to extract PCA component from a `fmat` matrix `m` (67584 x 396) using `princomp` function of Armadillo Library.
With the code below:

```
fmat eigenVec, score;
fvec eigenVal, t;
princomp(eigenVec, score, eigenVal, t, trans(m));
```

I get this error:

```
error: arma::memory::acquire(): out of memory

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

However, in other parts of the code I manage matrices bigger than this one(`m`).

I run this code on: Debian, 8GB of memory.

EDIT: I had this error

```
 error: Mat::init(): requested size is too large

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  Mat::init(): requested size is too large
```

before, and I had modified the file config.hpp to resolve (as in [C++ - framework for computing PCA (other than armadillo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480410/c-framework-for-computing-pca-other-than-armadillo))